# What are the actual ranges of floating point and double data types in C#?

Tags: c#, types, floating-point, double

I'm learning C# and trying to get a logical visual representation of the actual range of data types in C#.

I have moved through the integers and am now up to float and double data types.

1. 8 bits (1 byte), sbyte, -128 to 127.
2. 8 bits (1 byte), byte, 0 to 255.
3. 16 bits (2 bytes), short, -32,768 to 32,767.
4. 16 bits (2 bytes), ushort, 0 to 65535.
5. 32 bits (4 bytes), int, -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.
6. 32 bits (4 bytes), uint, 0 to 4,294,967,295.
7. 64 bits (8 bytes), long, -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
8. 64 bits (8 bytes), ulong, 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615.

Here are the references to float and double data types sizes at msdn:

Float:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza(v=vs.110).aspx

[image]

Double:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx

[image]

So, trying to keep with the convention of specifiying the actual range of numbers as in the numbered list above, what do these two ranges actually represent?

Comment: They represent the minimum and maximum values of `float` / `double`. What is it that you're confused about?

Comment: Is your question "what 10^x means?"

Comment: @Alexei Yes, maybe that's it. If I use a calculator to go 10 to the power of 324, i get 'infinity' (http://easycalculation.com/exponential-power.php). I am not a maths person so excuse the ignorance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ranges are represented in "exponential format" for conciseness. For example, +1.7e+308 means 17 followed by 307 zeros:

1,700,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000

So the exponential format is preferred for such large numbers. And the same goes for extremely small numbers.

Also, take a look at [this reading](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) by Jon Skeet.

Comment: Since they are studying these two data types, I think it would be good to know also that the float has a precision of 7 digits and double 15-16 digits because of they are represents in the IEEE754 standard.

Comment: @Eren so the range of a float is `negative 3.4 (followed by 38 zero's) to positive 3.4 (followed by 38 zero's)` and the range of a double is `negative 5.0 (followed by 324 zero's) to positive 1.7 (followed by 308 zero's)`?

Comment: well, I wouldn't say "-3.4 followed by zeros" as "-3.4000000000...." is still the same value as -3.4. But maybe say "-34 followed by 37 zeros", or more accurately: "-3.4 multiplied by 10 to the power of 38". Adding a good reading link to the answer.

Answer (score 11):

The ranges are actually –infinity to +infinity.

The largest **finite** `float` is 340282346638528859811704183484516925440. This is 2<sup>128</sup>–2<sup>128–24</sup>.

The largest **finite** `double` is 179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368. This is 2<sup>1024</sup>–2<sup>1024–53</sup>.

Comment: How is it 2 power 128 when size of float is only 32 bits?

Comment: @Shad: Floating-point formats do not encode numbers using binary (at least not just binary). The encode the number with a sign, a significand (often expressed in binary, but packed decimal and other alternatives may be used), and an exponent (often binary with a bias added). The significand can be nearly 2 (although it uses binary, it is scaled to be between 1 and 2), and the exponent in the typical `float` format can range from −126 to +127. It is an exponent of 2, so the maximum finite value is almost 2 (from the significand) times 2^127 (from the exponent).